# How do I use multiple createPage routes in gatsby-node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gatsby

Im currently having an issue when using multiple `createPage` routes in `gatsby-node.js`. I am trying to use Gatsby js with Shopify commerce storefront & and another CMS for blog articles so I need a way of creating routes when viewing products and when viewing blog articles respectively.

Currently, I am experiencing an error that only appears when trying to view a product detail page that reads:

`(EnsureResources, ) TypeError: Cannot read property 'page' of undefined`

My `gatsby-node.js` currently looks like this

```
const path = require(`path`)

// Create product page urls
exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  return graphql(`
    {
      allShopifyProduct {
        edges {
          node {
            handle
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then(result => {
    result.data.allShopifyProduct.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
        const id = node.handle
      createPage({
        path: `/product/${id}/`,
        component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/product-page.js`),
        context: {
            id,
        },
      })
    })
  })
}

// Create blog post slug urls
exports.createPages = async ({graphql, actions}) => {
  const {createPage} = actions
  const blogTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/blog.js')
  const res = await graphql (`
    query {
      allContentfulBlogPost {
        edges {
          node {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  res.data.allContentfulBlogPost.edges.forEach((edge) => {
    createPage ({
      component: blogTemplate,
      path: `/blog/${edge.node.slug}`,
      context: {
        slug: edge.node.slug
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't define the same API (`createPages`) twice. Do it in one function, especially since you can all put it into one query.

This code is obviously untested, but should work:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const result = await graphql(`
    {
      shopify: allShopifyProduct {
        nodes {
          handle
        }
      }
      contentful: allContentfulBlogPost {
        nodes {
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const shopifyTemplate = require.resolve(`./src/templates/product-page.js`)
  const contentfulTemplate = require.resolve('./src/templates/blog.js')

  if (result.errors) {
    return
  }

  result.data.shopify.nodes.forEach(product => {
    const id = product.handle

    createPage({
      path: `/product/${id}/`,
        component: shopifyTemplate,
        context: {
            id,
        },
    })
  })

  result.data.contentful.nodes.forEach(post => {
    createPage ({
      component: contentfulTemplate,
      path: `/blog/${post.slug}`,
      context: {
        slug: post.slug
      }
    })
  })
}
```

The `nodes` is a shortcut for `edges.node` and valid syntax. The `shopify:` is an alias before the name of the query. You don't need to use `path`, you can also use `require.resolve`. The async/await syntax is better to read IMO.

Comment: Would it be good to separate this into two promises, so they can run parallel?

Comment: Separating them wouldn't enable parallelisation (so it's not necessary). With Gatsby v4 you get that though: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/what-is-parallel-query-running/

Comment: I see, but it v4 still has some issues with gatsby-source-graphql, am I right? We use it in a combination with Strapi